# SignalR Reconnecting Event Not Firing Properly in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, event-handling, signalr, signalr.client

I'm writing a Xamarin Forms Android app that connects to a SignalR server. My goal is to alert the user when their server connection is lost, but when the `HubConnection.Reconnecting` Event is fired, the content of my handler (shown below) doesn't run. Here's the code:

```
public static class SignalRService
    {
        private static HubConnection _connection { get; set; }

        public static void SetupSignalRService(string url, string hubEndpoint)
        {
            _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"{url}/{hubEndpoint}")
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();

            _connection.Reconnecting += Connection_Reconnecting;

        }

        public static async Task Connect()
        {
            await _connection.StartAsync();
        }

        public static Task Connection_Reconnecting(Exception arg)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Reconnecting", "Check your server status.", "ok");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    }
```

When using breakpoints, I can see that the thread makes its way to the opening code block `{` and first line, but jumps out of the method after I continue. I've tried very similar code on a C# console app project which worked right away (with Console.WriteLine instead of DisplayAlert). Any ideas on what else I can try?

Comment: have you tried running the DisplayAlert on the MainThread?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to users/1338/jason for supplying the answer:

> have you tried running the DisplayAlert on the MainThread?

With the Xamarin.Essentials' `MainThread` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread), the code indeed worked:

```
public static Task Connection_Reconnecting(Exception arg)
{
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Reconnecting", "Check your server status.", "ok"));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```